# How can I keep track of many-to-many relationships in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a simple program that would match colleagues (2-4) for lunch every week. The matching is based on tenure at the company (less tenured colleagues to be matched with more tenured ones), but I'm struggling to find a way to account for recent matches. The idea is to every week find new groups of 2-4 people for lunch. Any ideas on how I could structure it in firestore to be able to check if the generated group of people have met before?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I haven’t started coding yet - I’m still trying to figure out how to design/structure this is firestore

Comment: Without knowing how *exactly* you intend to query your database, it's not possible to propose an option.  With NoSQL type databases, you must know the queries in order to model effectively.  You will also need an understanding of the size of the data set you're trying to store, and its growth requirements, so you can work within the constraints of Firestore.  There is no "one size fits all" like there is with SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a collection of meetings with a map field:

```
meetings (collection)
  meetingId (document)
    +participants: {
      participantId1: true,
      participantId2: true
    }
```

Against this I can find if two people have met before by:

```
meetingsCollection
  .where('participants.participantId1', '==', true)
  .where('participants.participantId2', '==', true)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really "maintaining" a many-to-many situation. What you are describing is more related to documents being generated for essential meetings of randomized users.

You could use a flag on users's documents who are available, and depending on your needs, prompt the user to find active/pending meetings that involve them as a participant. You would do this with an array of strings, the strings being the user-id

Structure:

```
Firestore:
  users (collection)
    userId (document)
      +available:true/false
  meetings (collection)
    randomMeetingId (document)
      +participants: ["userID"]
      +timeAt:timeOfMeeting
```

From there, you would use queries and Cloud Functions to maintain these meetings based on current meeting participants of userId and `meeting.timeAt` being expired. Additionally, you can react to changes with the users available and status, etc.